# why can't I reimplement my tensorflow model with pytorch?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I am developing a model in tensorflow and find that it is good on my specific evaluation method. But when I transfer to pytorch, I can't achieve the same results. I have checked the model architecture, the weight init method, the lr schedule, the weight decay, momentum and epsilon used in BN layer, the optimizer, and the data preprocessing. All things are the same. But I can't get the same results as in tensorflow. Anybody have met the same problem?

Comment: Please add more details.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar conversion recently.

First you need to make sure that the forward path produces the same results: disable all randomness, initialize with the same values, give it a very small input and compare. If there is a discrepancy, disable parts of the network and compare enabling layers one by one.

When the forward path is confirmed, check the loss, gradients, and updates after one forward-backward cycle.

Comment: I am using resnet 110 as the backbone. How do you copy your weights out of tensorflow model? Do you use numpy as the bridge?

Comment: It's probably easier just to initialize both models with the same values (like 0.1 for all weights, you can write a loop through all parameters assigning this value), no randomness, no training.

Comment: thank you. It is good. I just dump all the weights in TF model into pytorch model.

Comment: I have dumped all the tensorflow model weights into pytorch model.
I use a simple input in test and find that the forward pass and the backward pass are all the same.
In my case, I use resnet110 as the backbone. The dataset is cifar10.
The only difference is that I use cifar10 bin version in TF and cifar10 python version in pytorch.
Except this, the two models use the same initial weight, the same optimizer (SGD with momentum 0.9), the same batch normalization layer with momentum=0.99,epsilon=1e-3, the same lr schedule and weight decay=2e-4.
But the results in pytorch are still worse.

Comment: The difference must be somewhere. Is the loss the same after one iteration? Are the updates the same after one iteration? Another thing, how exactly are you evaluating performance? (you probably need to switch the model into evaluation mode with `model.eval()` to make batchnorm work properly)

Comment: I have checked the forward pass and the loss value, the backward pass and after one update step, they are all the same.I also invoke model.eval() before evaluation. In fact, the pytorch model work better than TF model on the classification, I can't achieve the same classification accuracy in TF, but on my another criterion, pytorch model is worse than TF model.